# Does reciting the 99 Names of ALLAH (swt) bring particular benefits?

Tags: islamic-basis, asma-ul-husna

I happened to visit a Islamic website [99 Names of ALLAH(swt)](http://www.duas.org/nallah.htm) recently, and it had listed all the names of ALLAH (swt), with all the names there is a certain **WAZIFA** or say certain recitations, that if a certain name is recited 100 times then this benefit will happen.

**For example :**  If a person recites *Ar-Rehman* **100** times then he will get sharp memory.

Is there any validity to this practice?  In particular, **can anyone provide me with some authentic ahadith** or any reference in **Al-Quran** regarding it?

Answer (score 3):

No.
Those are pure fabrications most probably based on Jewish mythology. Quran doesn't support that.
But thinking about them does benefit you.You should contemplate on them instead. Look 3:191, 4:103. You don't have to learn or memorize them in Arabic. You should learn their meanings instead. Look 17:110. Think about them in the context of surahs and try to connect the meaning of the beautiful name with the story told in the surah. For further reading I recommend the book Exploring Islam In A New Light by Abdur RAb. You can buy the ebook online.